# Ajax call returning full page HTML instead of desired data

Tags: php, jquery, html, ajax

I am trying to create an Ajax live search, but the Ajax call is returning the full HTML instead of the usernames I am looking for. I experimented around with procedural instead of PDO and it worked perfectly fine but I am trying to keep my whole project PDO. I'm not quite sure what would cause it to send the HTML instead of the expected result. I'm also receiving no errors in the console. Thanks for your help.

### index.php

```
$("#check-input").keyup(function() {
    var inputVal = $(this).val();
    var resultDropdown = $(this).siblings(".check-input-result");
     if (inputVal.length) {
         $.get("php_backend/backend-search.php", {
             term: inputVal
         }).done(function(data) {
             resultDropdown.html(data);
         });
      } else {
          resultDropdown.empty();
      }
});
```

### backend-search.php

```
<?php

try{
    $pdo = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=demo", "root", "");
    $pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
} catch(PDOException $e){
    die("ERROR: Could not connect. " . $e->getMessage());
}

try{
    if(isset($_REQUEST['term'])){        
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE username LIKE :term";
        $stmt = $pdo->prepare($sql);
        $term = $_REQUEST['term'] . '%';
        $stmt->bindParam(':term', $term);
        $stmt->execute();

        if($stmt->rowCount() > 0){
            while($row = $stmt->fetch()){
                echo "<p>" . $row['username'] . "</p>";
            }
        } else{
            echo "<p>No matches found</p>";
        }
    }  
} catch(PDOException $e){
    die("ERROR: Could not able to execute $sql. " . $e->getMessage());
}

unset($stmt);
unset($pdo);

?>
```

Comment: What is the output you are getting from this?

Comment: I am getting my HTML source code.

Comment: Can you post that here?

Answer (score 0):

instead of `echo` use `return` to sending data(without any html).

```
$data = [];
if($stmt->rowCount() > 0){
   while($row = $stmt->fetch()){
      array_push($row['username']);
   }
}
return $data;
```

loop through the data inside `.done()` method and add necessary html to display.